# Do not resize/stretch camera preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, preview

Here is my camera Holder:

```
            <SurfaceView
                android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp" />
```

My problem is that android stretches the camera preview and even if I set PreviewSize that doesn't work !! 
PLEASE HELP !

Comment: Take a look at the use of AspectFrameLayout in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika), e.g. in PlayMovieSurfaceActivity.

Answer (score 0):

SurfaceView, unlike ImageView, has no built-in procedure to keep its aspect ratio. The available schemes to overcome this deficit are split between embedding the SurfaceView in a container with controlled width and height, and setting width and height of the SurfaceView in `onMeasure()`.

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVED]   [IT WORKS] [:D]

I have resolved the problem like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/mySurfaceView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

             //  put widgets here
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:src="@drawable/my_mask" /> //put a transparent image or         a mask for your SurfaceView


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            //  put widgets here
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

PS: Don't forget to like if it works for you too ;)

Comment: This is not a universal solution. It presumes that camera preview aspect ratio matches aspect ratio of the screen, which does not fit many devices (e.g. Nexus 4).